# centering text vertically and horizontally in same table cell with image floated left

Tags: html, css

I know this probably seems like a little problem.  It just feels like there should be an easy solution. I have a feeling I'm SOL but I figured I'd ask first.

http://jsfiddle.net/bczengel/FSDz9/5/

### Problem:

When the image is not floated left it has the desired end result where the image and the text are both vertically centered.  When you float the image left the image is vertically centered and the text is aligned with the top of the image.

### Requirements:

- One table cell
- CSS only with the given html (or minimal changes to the html)
- I would like to avoid a line-height solution because the stylesheet is applied to many existing pages some of which have multiple lines in the text

Answer (score 24, accepted):

with a minimal html change (wrapping your title text in a `<p>`)

```css
table {
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

table td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

table td img {
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

table td p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 430px;
    background: #ccc;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img alt="test" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-nkjB-srUT_dc7brfRDiDSVu8BQa_6TEbQYevP1gy2UkTdcXWzg" />
      <p>Title Text</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br /><br />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img alt="test" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ-nkjB-srUT_dc7brfRDiDSVu8BQa_6TEbQYevP1gy2UkTdcXWzg" />
      <p>Title Text <br /> on the next line</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Unfortunately I forgot to mention I'm working on an old application that supports IE7 still and runs in Quirksmode (We're rewriting ground up soon). Doesn't change the fact that you answered my posted question perfectly.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the negative margin method to vertically center the text. To do that you could put your text in a `<span>` and have the following css:

```
table
{
    width: 500px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

table td
{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

table td img
{
    width: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table.float td img
{
    float: left;
}

table.float td span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px; /* or half of the height of your text */
}
```

Comment: it will need a lot of adjustments in his case - _" the stylesheet is applied to many existing pages some of which have multiple lines in the text"_